# Can i put a data into a table in 'Codeigniter', but the data is a 'function()'?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have successfully done 'echo' in this 'function()', and the result went out....

The problem is, when I try to put it into a table in the database, only Photos are successful, but other data does not go into the table

in Controller Home.php

```
public function insert_data()
{
  $config['upload_path']     = 'users/images/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
  $config['overwrite']       = TRUE;

  $data_img_post = array();
  if ( isset($_FILES['images-post']) ) {
    $IMAGE           = $_FILES['images-post'];
    $COUNT_IMAGE = count($IMAGE['name']);

    for ($i=0; $i < $COUNT_IMAGE; $i++) {
      $_FILES['images-post']['name']         = $IMAGE['name'][$i];
      $_FILES['images-post']['type']         = $IMAGE['type'][$i];
      $_FILES['images-post']['tmp_name'] = $IMAGE['tmp_name'][$i];
      $_FILES['images-post']['error']        = $IMAGE['error'][$i];
      $_FILES['images-post']['size']         = $IMAGE['size'][$i];
      $this->upload->initialize($config);
      $this->upload->do_upload('images-post');
      $data_img_post[] = $this->upload->data();
    }
  }

  $data_post = array(
    'dbi_post_user_name'          => $info->dbi_user_name,
    'dbi_post_username'           => $info->dbi_username,
    'dbi_post_user_gender'    => $info->dbi_user_gender,
    'dbi_post_content'            => $this->input->post('content-post'),
    'dbi_post_tags'                     => $this->input->post('tags'),
    'dbi_post_select_privacy'   => $this->input->post('privacy-select'),
    'dbi_post_dir_image'            => $this->get_file_name($data_img_post)
  );
  $this->users_model->insert_data_post($data_post);
}

private function get_file_name($data_img_post){
  $COUNT_DATA_IMG = count($data_img_post);
  for ($i=0; $i < $COUNT_DATA_IMG; $i++) {
    echo $data_img_post[$i]['file_name'].' ';
  }
}
```

in Ajax XHR.js

```
$('#form-create-post').submit(function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url     : "home",
    type    : "post",
    data    : new FormData(this),
    cache       : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    success : function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Please correct my mistake :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your `private function() get_file_name()` and TRY THIS

```
public function index()
{
  $config['upload_path']     = 'users/'.$info->dbi_username.'./images/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
  $config['overwrite']       = TRUE;

  $data_img_post = array();
  if ( isset($_FILES['images-post']) ) {
    $IMAGE           = $_FILES['images-post'];
    $COUNT_IMAGE = count($IMAGE['name']);

    for ($i=0; $i < $COUNT_IMAGE; $i++) {
      $_FILES['images-post']['name']         = $IMAGE['name'][$i];
      $_FILES['images-post']['type']         = $IMAGE['type'][$i];
      $_FILES['images-post']['tmp_name'] = $IMAGE['tmp_name'][$i];
      $_FILES['images-post']['error']        = $IMAGE['error'][$i];
      $_FILES['images-post']['size']         = $IMAGE['size'][$i];
      $this->upload->initialize($config);
      $this->upload->do_upload('images-post');
      $data_img_post[] = $this->upload->data();
    }
  }

  $result_array = array();
  $COUNT_DATA_IMG = count($data_img_post);
  for ($i=0; $i < $COUNT_DATA_IMG; $i++) {
    $result_array[] = $data_img_post[$i]['file_name'].' ';
  }

  $array_to_string = implode(' ', $result_array);

  $data_post = array(
    'dbi_post_user_name'          => $info->dbi_user_name,
    'dbi_post_username'           => $info->dbi_username,
    'dbi_post_user_gender'    => $info->dbi_user_gender,
    'dbi_post_content'            => $this->input->post('content-post'),
    'dbi_post_tags'                     => $this->input->post('tags'),
    'dbi_post_select_privacy'   => $this->input->post('privacy-select'),
    'dbi_post_dir_image'            => $array_to_string
  );
  $this->users_model->insert_data_post($data_post);
}
```

Comment: Wow, very awesome THX :D